# Landscape mode can not show two fragments

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-fragments

I just create an app with listview and webview. The portrait mode is work fine.
But when I turn the phone in landscape mode(android studio emulator), It has unknown Buffer

> 04-28 14:07:42.822 2202-2216/shiweichen22gmail.q1 E/Surface:
>   getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab7926c0

I want to the left part can shows the fragment with `list-view` and right part shows the fragment with `web-view`. But it only shows the fragment with `list-view`.
I already create android resource directory with landscape layout (it can not found in android, only can found in project )

**Here is my code**
`Portrait.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="shiweichen22gmail.q1.Portrait"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_portrait">

<fragment
    android:id ="@+id/fragment1"
    class ="shiweichen22gmail.q1.List"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     />
</LinearLayout>
```

`Landscape Layout.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:name="shiweichen22gmail.q1.List"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</fragment>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/detail"
    android:name="shiweichen22gmail.q1.Detail"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omRHE.jpg)xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="shiweichen22gmail.q1">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<user-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".Portrait"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Landscape"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_landscape"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Portiat.java

```
package shiweichen22gmail.q1;

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;




public class Portrait extends FragmentActivity implements     List.OnSiteSelectedListener{
Detail web;
List list;
FragmentManager manager;

@Override

public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if(newConfig.orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){

        Log.e("On Config Change", "LANDSCAPE");
    }else{

        Log.e("On Config Change","PORTRAIT");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_portrait);
    manager = getFragmentManager();
    list = (List)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1);
    list.setRefrence(this);

}
@Override
public void onSiteSelected(int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    web = (Detail)   getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detail);
        // Check for content_portrait mode
        if (web!= null && web.isVisible())
        {
            web.setNewPage(i);
        }
        else
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Landscape.class);
            intent.putExtra("index", i);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }


}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omRHE.jpg)

Comment: your portait and landscape layout inflated in same activity ? If yes please add activity code too

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html

Comment: I just change rename some files in case confusion. I think the main issue here is that the emulator can not find the landscape layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you are registering two activity in manifest? The **name of both layout file(Land+Port) must be same**.

This way your activity will choose which layout to pick automatically.

**Important :-** But before adding reference to your layouts and adding listeners on views in activity class you must check what current orientation is other wise it will result into NullPointer crash as you will be trying to take reference of view which is not inflated.

**What you need to do :-**

- Remove Landscape activity from manifest
- Change name of landscape layout same as portrait and move it to layout-land folder in resource directory .
- Before using findviewbyId in activity class you must check if current orientation is land or port.

**Example Working Code**

Main Activity class

public class HomeActivity extends FragmentActivity {

```
private UniversalWebViewFragment detailFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_activity);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.selector);

    final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        //Load random Google search URLS for List
        list.add("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + i);
    }

    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list));

    if (!isPortrait(getApplicationContext())) {
        detailFragment = (UniversalWebViewFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.webView);
    }

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

            if (isPortrait(getApplicationContext())) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Do Fragment Transition with URL" + list.get(arg2), 300).show();

            } else {

                if (null != detailFragment)
                    detailFragment.loadURL(list.get(arg2));

            }
        }
    });

}
//Check if device is in portrait mode
public static boolean isPortrait(Context context) {

    return context.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_portrait);
}
```

}

res/layout/home_activity.xml

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/selector"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >
</ListView>
```

res/layout-land/home_activity.xml

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/selector"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >
</ListView>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/selector"
    class="com.masterdetail_webview.UniversalWebViewFragment" />
```

**Detecting device orientation**

res/values/layouts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="is_portrait">true</bool>
</resources>
```

res/values-land/layouts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="is_portrait">false</bool>
</resources>
```

**Extras showing web contents with the help of** **[UniversalWebViewFragment](https://github.com/hiteshsahu/Android-Universal-Web-Content-Loader)**

Loading webcontents in fragment simply drop this class in your project

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnCancelListener;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class UniversalWebViewFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String WEB_URL_TO_LOAD = "webURLToLoad";

    private static final String GOOGLE_SERACH_URL = "https://www.google.com/search?q=";

    private WebView webView;
    private FrameLayout customViewContainer;
    private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback customViewCallback;
    private View mCustomView;
    private myWebChromeClient mWebChromeClient;
    private myWebViewClient mWebViewClient;

    public static UniversalWebViewFragment newInstance(String webUrl, boolean serachOnWeb) {
        Bundle bdl = new Bundle();
        if (serachOnWeb) {
            // serach on google for query
            bdl.putString(WEB_URL_TO_LOAD, GOOGLE_SERACH_URL + webUrl);
        } else {

            // seimply load url
            bdl.putString(WEB_URL_TO_LOAD, webUrl);
        }
        UniversalWebViewFragment newInstance = new UniversalWebViewFragment();
        newInstance.setArguments(bdl);
        return newInstance;
    }

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.universal_web_view, container, false);

        // if (null != getArguments() && null !=
        // getArguments().getString(WEB_URL_TO_LOAD)) {
        customViewContainer = (FrameLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.customViewContainer);
        webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView);

        mWebViewClient = new myWebViewClient();
        webView.setWebViewClient(mWebViewClient);

        mWebChromeClient = new myWebChromeClient();
        webView.setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // Important for PayUMoney
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
        loadURL(GOOGLE_SERACH_URL);
        // webView.requestFocus();

        // Handle Back keyPress
        rootView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        rootView.requestFocus();
        rootView.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

                    if (inCustomView()) {
                        hideCustomView();
                        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();

                        return true;
                    }

                    if ((mCustomView == null) && webView.canGoBack()) {
                        webView.goBack();

                        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();

                        return true;

                    }
                }
                // return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
                return true;
            }
        });
        // }

        return rootView;
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    public void loadURL(String URl) {
        webView.loadUrl(URl);
    }

    public boolean inCustomView() {
        return (mCustomView != null);
    }

    public void hideCustomView() {
        mWebChromeClient.onHideCustomView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause(); // To change body of overridden methods use File |
                            // Settings | File Templates.
        webView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume(); // To change body of overridden methods use File |
                            // Settings | File Templates.
        webView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop(); // To change body of overridden methods use File |
                        // Settings | File Templates.
        if (inCustomView()) {
            hideCustomView();
        }
    }

    class myWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        private View mVideoProgressView;

        @Override
        public void onShowCustomView(View view, int requestedOrientation, CustomViewCallback callback) {
            onShowCustomView(view, callback); // To change body of overridden
                                                // methods use File | Settings |
                                                // File Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {

            // if a view already exists then immediately terminate the new one
            if (mCustomView != null) {
                callback.onCustomViewHidden();
                return;
            }
            mCustomView = view;
            webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            customViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            customViewContainer.addView(view);
            customViewCallback = callback;
        }

        @Override
        public View getVideoLoadingProgressView() {

            if (mVideoProgressView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
                mVideoProgressView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_progress, null);
            }
            return mVideoProgressView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onHideCustomView() {
            super.onHideCustomView(); // To change body of overridden methods
                                        // use File | Settings | File Templates.
            if (mCustomView == null)
                return;

            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            customViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // Hide the custom view.
            mCustomView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // Remove the custom view from its container.
            customViewContainer.removeView(mCustomView);
            customViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();

            mCustomView = null;
        }
    }

    class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }

        private int webViewPreviousState;

        private final int PAGE_STARTED = 0x1;

        private final int PAGE_REDIRECTED = 0x2;

        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            webViewPreviousState = PAGE_STARTED;

            if (dialog == null || !dialog.isShowing())
                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "", "Loading Please Wait", true, true,
                        new OnCancelListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                                // do something
                            }
                        });
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            if (webViewPreviousState == PAGE_STARTED) {
                if (null != dialog)
                    dialog.dismiss();
                dialog = null;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

res/layout/universal_web_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <WebView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/customViewContainer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

Extra layout for youtube progress(just in case)

res/ video_progress

```
<ProgressBar android:id="@android:id/progress"
             style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView android:paddingTop="5dip"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:text="loading"
          android:textSize="14sp"
          android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"/>
```

**result :- I am in secured proxy network it will look nice in open net**

[image: masterdetail webview]

Comment: Thanks a lot. But when I click the listview, the webview have the whole screen rather than fragment with list view on the left side and fragment with webview on the right side. What kind of code should i add in before fingviewbyid

Comment: see edit I have added sample code you can modify it as you want

Comment: Thanks, It really helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

No need to handle two xml in your case
just add both in your main activity and give weight like 0.5 for both.
and check if your is portrait mode then hide one fragment and when user is landscape visible second fragment.

**and one more thing you are not set max weight first sex max weight.**
and most imp add one line in menifest.xml

```
 android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
```

and if you want to do some code when orientation change then you can override onConfigurationChanged() method

```
 @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // write here code
   // here you can check orientation and set your code as per your requirement
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to override `onConfigurationChanged()` in your Activity.

```
@Override

 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

   super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

 }
```

Comment: Thanks, but not working. The landscape layout is created successfully, but i think the emulator cannot find the landscape layout when it is running

Comment: @Albert : You can move your emulator to landscape mode using num pad 9 key press.

Comment: when i move to landscape mode, it only has one fragment(listview) rather than two fragments(listview and webview)